# VBA-JSON converting json to excel and vice-versa

Tags: json, vba, string

VBA-json doesn't detect error when there is a missing comma (,) in json string how to resolve that.

I have been using the https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas for converting json to excel.

If there is anyother way we can use to verify if the string is valid json string please suggest.

{
"applicationId" : "5"
"name" : "Noddy",
}
So as in the above json there isn't any , after applicationId but still it doesn't show any error , so how can we resolve it?

Comment: In which circumstances "a missing comma" may exist? It has been created to usually download it from an existing/working internet page. Do you manually try building such a string? And json is not really "converted" to excel... The mentioned solution returns a Dictionary, which can be used to drop data in an Excel sheet. Filtering it before, according to some criteria (if needed), or using/dropping everything.

Comment: Please provide a sample JSON that shows the issue.

Comment: Actually what I require is that whenever we import a json file so we just need to check if the imported json is a valid json string or not.    @FaneDuru

Comment: I just run a quick test using JSONConverter on the JSON in your question and it does come back with an error. Please show your code in the question. @Hemans19

Comment: { "applicationId" : "5" "name" : "Noddy" , "city" : " NY"} for me I don't know why it doesn't throw any error @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 Please show your code.

Comment: Actually I am working on some sensitive data so can you please show your code @Raymond Wu

Comment: I'm asking for the code that shows how you use JSONConverter, not the JSON string. Do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code? @Hemans19

Comment: Yes it is present in the vba inside the convertToJson function @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 You should be using `ParseJSON` to convert a JSON `String` to a `Dictionary` object, not `ConvertToJSON`. @Hemans19

Comment: I am using JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText) as to convert the json to excel and in it I haven't added On Error Resume Next so if it's possible to do so can you please tell how to do it? @Raymond Wu

Comment: What about the code that has the line `JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)`? Does it have On Error Resume Next? You are not making it easier for us to help you as you can't even provide a [minimal producible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), just a snippet of the code and reduct the sensitive data if any (which you shouldn't even have it in your code).

Comment: This is exactly what I have in my code and I can get the error `Dim testDict As Scripting.Dictionary`, `JsonConverter.ParseJson("{ ""applicationId"" : ""5"" ""name"" : ""Noddy"", }")` so there's nothing to show you! @Hemans19

Comment: Dim testDict As Scripting.Dictionary
JsonConverter.ParseJson ("{ ""applicationId"" : ""5"" ""name"" : ""Noddy"" }")   it doesn't give any error which it should have given as there is no (,) between the 2 json objects @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 I can reproduce this but the conversion is correct still (the dictionary has 2 keys and the values for both keys are correct), the converter seems to be able to handle the lack of delimiter as long as the key/value structure is there. What I'm really concerned with is, where is the source of this JSON? It's very unlikely that an API call will return an invalid JSON string so did you build this yourself or what?

Comment: Actually the json was already built manually by some user, they are not coming from any API and what I want is import those json files and check if there is any error or not , if there is no error just convert it to excel. @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 Given that the converter has no issue with sample you gave (although it's strictly invalid), I'm not sure what's better, you find another way to validate the JSON string or you actually fix the root issue (the user who built the json). Today you might find a missing ",", who knows what happen next?

Comment: Isn't there any other way through which we can check the json string? @Raymond Wu

Comment: For realistic purpose, invalid JSON is not really an issue we should expect to receive but a weird way I can think of is perhaps open Internet Explorer, navigate to `http://json.parser.online.fr/`, paste the string there and then check if the parser returns an error in the parse header. It's a theory but should be doable. @Hemans19

Comment: thanks but it won't help tho @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 I'm out of idea then, see if anyone can help you in your new question.

Comment: Don't we have a regex in vba which can check the json string ? @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Hemans19 if the data structure of your json string is always fixed, that might be possible, but is it?

Comment: Ya it is indeed @Raymond Wu

Comment: You can try it out then, plenty of regex guide online. However i must say that validating using regex is not exactly a good way to be sure that a json is valid. @Hemans19

Comment: OK thanks @Raymond Wu