# Json string check VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba, string, github

I am trying to parse a json file which has a (,) missing between the objects, using the VBA-JSON github project ( https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas ) but it does not give any error and converts the json to excel successfully how can I point out the missing (,) ?

Json file looks like this;-

```
{    
   "hotel": "5-star"

   "spa-available": true,

   "restaurant-menu": [
      
{

         "dish": "Pizza",
         "order": 1,
         "ketch-up": true,
         "price": "25",
         "extra-cheese": "yes"
      },

      {
         "dish": "Burger",
         "order": 2,
         "ketch-up": true,
         "price": "12",
         "extra-cheese": "no"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I asked you, when place your first similar question, something like: Where from the JSON to be processed is taken and you did not answer my clarification question. Isn't it extracted from an internet source/page? If so, how can it be inconsistent? If not, the way of issuing should be changed, I am afraid. So, can you clarify this issue? And, in the example you provided now, are you referring to `"hotel": "5-star"` line? If so, how is it returned when converted? Correctly, or followed by `"spa-available": true`, in the same dictionary key?

Comment: @FaneDuru He has answered the source in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315234/vba-json-converting-json-to-excel-and-vice-versa#comment122614730_69315234) later - built by someone else.

Comment: @Raymond Wu I have not been tagged and then, not notified. I cannot keep all the questions, where I ask for clarification, open. In such a case to not pay that "someone else" and ask him to correct the creation  algorithm... I think, I can imagine a correction algorithm, based on the JSON building logic, which is not so complicated (the JSON building, I mean), but it should be complicated to process an already built such a string. And why doing that, of instead asking to the supplier to deliver a correct one?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, I'm just pointing you to the answer to your clarification question (which he replied today).

Comment: Actually the json has to validated and the supplier has already left , can you please provide any logic like if there is already an existing json then how can we check if it is valid or not? @FaneDuru

Comment: The logic of JSON building can be seen on github, too. [Here, for instance](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsonp001.html). Do you still have the source which the left supplier used to use? Not necessarily the code source (even if it should be the best), **based on what did he create the JSON in discussion**? Theoretically, it should be easier to rebuild it than correct/validate it...

Comment: Acutally the supplier used to build it manually and because of which few json which he created have some errors like few of the files have missing (,) so I just wanted a validator ,if the validator can just tell if the json is valid or not. @FaneDuru

Comment: Manually, manually, but based on what? Did he make it according to what he supposed you need?

Comment: yes he made it according to the need earlier @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of a validator (other than JSONConverter that seems to have no issue in the first place) so this method utilise the parser in http://json.parser.online.fr/:

```
Private Sub ValidateJSONByIE()

    Dim jsontxt As String
    jsontxt = OpenTxtFile("path of the JSON file")
    
    Dim ieObj As Object
    Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    
    ieObj.Visible = True 'Remove if do not need IE to be visible
    ieObj.navigate "http://json.parser.online.fr/"
    Do While ieObj.Busy Or ieObj.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set ieDoc = ieObj.Document
    
    Dim inputEle As Object
    Set inputEle = ieDoc.getElementById("eT")
    inputEle.Value = jsontxt
    inputEle.Click
    
    Dim parseEle As Object
    Set parseEle = ieDoc.getElementById("hW")
    
    If InStr(parseEle.innerText, "error") <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Error"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Error"
    End If
    
    ieObj.Quit
    Set ieObj = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Function OpenTxtFile(argPath As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim txtFile As Object
    Set txtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(argPath)
    
    OpenTxtFile = txtFile.ReadAll
    
    txtFile.Close
    Set txtFile = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Function
```